# I am trying to log into site specific metas, and can't

Tags: support, login, per-site-meta, google-chrome

I can visit meta.anysite.se.com, but when I click login, says at the bottom:

`Waiting for webapps.stackexchange.com` then `Waiting for meta.webapps.stackexchange.com` then `Processing request...` then it just doesn't load.

I am logged in to the main site.

This is the error console of Google Chrome.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of undefined          VM447:100
 getLoggedInUserId                                                     VM447:100
 (anonymous function)                                                  VM447:11
 n                                                                     jquery.min.js:2
 o.add                                                                 jquery.min.js:2
 StackExchange.ready                                                   stub.en.js?v=f919f4746b32:1
 (anonymous function)                                                  VM447:2
 (anonymous function)                                                  VM4 47:515
 with_jquery                                                           autoreviewcomments.js:52
 (anonymous function)                                                  autoreviewcomments.js:55
```

Clearing browsing data for the past day hasn't helped. It does work in Firefox, though.

The other (duplicates) didn't work.

Comment: Any browser extensions? Security software that might inject JS into pages?

Comment: @Shadow yeah, it is an extension (tried in incognito which disables them). Just have to find out which...

Comment: It was power switch - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lljbpnomhjlnohbcipjjjmnbncfofobe

Comment: Nice, please post this as answer so others having same issue will see. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that this is a problem with a specific Google Chrome extension: [Power Switch](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lljbpnomhjlnohbcipjjjmnbncfofobe).

To test if it is an extension causing the problem, go into incognito, they are all automatically disabled. If it then works, that's the problem. Then I went though disabling each one.